# feature request for editing - suppress BTTT

Tags: feature-request, editing

Can we get an option added to the edit page that will allow an editor to suppress "back to the top" behavior?

This will allow an editor to make a perhaps trivial change without wasting the time of daily chess.SO readers.

Comment: You can filter out activity when [sorting questions](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest), if you don't want to see what's new. If you want to see what's been added, search for the most recent activity's originator in the answer list, if that's an edit, you probably lost <10s. <3s if the answers are sorted by activity and you just have to check the first one. I would call flooding the home page more of a problem (when pushing more valuable new content down the page).

Comment: [Some people agree with you](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6549988#6549988), by the way. I'm surprised not to find this feature-request on MSO, actually (I'd support it there). [If I really want to find it, I guess I could post it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156053/197593)